# ServiceStack.text not Load file System.Memory

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

Good morning,
we are developing a dll that uses ServiceStack.Text.dll (5.4).
The installation in the project was done via nuget.
Locally the application works fine while on a server machine it has problems.
The following error occurs when loaded into memory and run on in Windows Server 2012 r2 standard .
We have the following error:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.IO .FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version = 4.0.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.

The system cannot find the file specified.
But in our build folder the indicated system.memory is available and also its dependencies.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need an Assembly Binding in your `Web.Config` (or `App.Config` for non Web Apps) to reference the version of **System.Memory** your project has referenced, something like:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" 
            publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: I entered the reference on the confing app. Now I have a different mistake.
** Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**


The System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll it's present in the folder

Comment: Config file it is the seguent:
` <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe"
            publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory"
            publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>`

Comment: @ruosco82 you need to keep adding [assembly bindings](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx#resolving-runtime-assembly-loading-issues) to reference the assembly versions your project does have referenced to tell the .NET Runtime which versions they should use.

Comment: We updated the .config with all the dlls present in the project (system.buffer, System.Numerics.Vectors ect) but the error is always the same

'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version = 4.0.4.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

We also tried to register the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe dll in the GAC

Other suggestions?

Comment: @ruosco82 you need to make sure you're referencing the correct Assembly Version by inspecting the version in the Assembly Metadata, i.e. it's not the same as the NuGet version, e.g. the latest 4.7.1 on NuGet has an [Assembly Version of 4.0.6.0](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1128#issuecomment-582179713).

Comment: It is a problem of net framework updates.
Even if the 4.8 net framework is installed on the server machine some support libraries (eg System.Memory) are an older version than my current machine even if I have installed an older framework (4.7.2).
I have to check what updates I have made in my PC that have updated the 4.72 framework